# What is the meaning of # inside the input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am going through an article of angular2 where they use `<input type='text' #hobby>`. With the help of #hobby they are extracting the value which are typing inside the textbox in place of taking ngModal. I am not getting that is #hobby means.

Comment: it is selector like id

Comment: If it's inside a hyperlink, it means to jump to an anchor named "hobby" somewhere in the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`#`**, inside input, indicates that you are dealing with a local variable. 
Its an Angular2 way of defining a local variable in HTML. **`#`** will work behind the scene and updates your variable with relevant value.

```
<input type='text' #hobby>
```

Here **`hobby`** refers to a local variable as it is defined with **`#`** symbol. If you type in something in textbox, **`hobby`** variable will be updated immediately and you can access updated value by  **`something.value`** syntax so **`hobby.value`** will give you updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your template (html):

```
<button (click)="clicked(hobby)">Click</button>
```

This add to your component class:

```
clicked(a) {
  console.log(a);
}
```

You will see what that means.

Answer (score 0):

See [Template Syntax > Referencing a template reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#referencing-a-template-reference-variable).

> The hash (#) prefix to "[hobby]" means that we're defining a [hobby] variable.

It is the same as using the `ref-hobby` attribute and allows you to access the content of the variable, for example in click handlers.

```
<input #hobby>
<button (click)="something(hobby.value)">Do Something</button>
```